# Statistics update different based on compatibility modes

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand why statistics are behaving differently with compatibility between `130-150` and `160`.

Here are two test scenarios

Test scenarios 1:

```
USE master;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'StatisticsUpdating')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE StatisticsUpdating SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE StatisticsUpdating;
END

GO

CREATE DATABASE StatisticsUpdating;

GO

ALTER DATABASE StatisticsUpdating SET 
    COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 160,
    AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON,
    AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;

GO

USE StatisticsUpdating;

CREATE TABLE StatMan
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    StatName VARCHAR(100),
    StatDescription VARCHAR(200)
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

CREATE TABLE StatInformation
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    StatManId INT NOT NULL,
    StatLineItem VARCHAR(200)
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO StatMan(StatName, StatDescription)
VALUES('Test3', 'Test Description');

GO 1000

SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO StatMan(StatName, StatDescription)
VALUES('Test3', 'Test Description');

GO 60000

SELECT 'DONE';
```

When viewing the `modification_counter` with the below query:

```
USE StatisticsUpdating;

SELECT s.object_id, sp.modification_counter, s.name,
CONCAT('USE ', DB_NAME(), ';', ' DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id)), ', ', QUOTENAME(s.name), ');') AS ViewHistogram
FROM sys.stats s
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id, s.stats_id) sp
WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('StatMan');
```

I get a `modification_counter` of `60,000`, as expected.

After running the below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

`modification_counter` is`0` as expected.

Everything is working as expected so far.

Now running the same test but switching the `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` to either `130`, `140`, or `150`.

When viewing the `modification_counter` with the below query:

```
USE StatisticsUpdating;

SELECT s.object_id, sp.modification_counter, s.name,
CONCAT('USE ', DB_NAME(), ';', ' DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id)), ', ', QUOTENAME(s.name), ');') AS ViewHistogram
FROM sys.stats s
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id, s.stats_id) sp
WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('StatMan');
```

I get a `modification_counter` of `NULL`, which is not expected.

When I run

```
SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Once again `modification_counter` is `NULL`, which is not expected.

So I'm really confused about why `modification_counter` is never getting any modifications, no matter how many rows are in the table.  Even running

```
USE StatisticsUpdating; 
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS([StatMan], [PK__StatMan__3214EC078268D31F]);
```

Shows no stats.

Test scenarios 2:

```
USE master;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'StatisticsUpdating')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE StatisticsUpdating SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE StatisticsUpdating;
END

GO

CREATE DATABASE StatisticsUpdating;

GO

ALTER DATABASE StatisticsUpdating SET 
    COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 160,
    AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON,
    AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;

GO

USE StatisticsUpdating;

CREATE TABLE StatMan
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    StatName VARCHAR(100),
    StatDescription VARCHAR(200)
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

CREATE TABLE StatInformation
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    StatManId INT NOT NULL,
    StatLineItem VARCHAR(200)
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO StatMan(StatName, StatDescription)
VALUES('Test3', 'Test Description');

INSERT INTO StatInformation(StatManId, StatLineItem)
SELECT Id, CONCAT('Test Item', CAST(Id AS CHAR(200)))
FROM StatMan
WHERE Id NOT IN
(
    SELECT StatManId
    FROM StatInformation
);

GO 1000

SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO StatMan(StatName, StatDescription)
VALUES('Test3', 'Test Description');

GO 60000

SELECT 'DONE';
```

When viewing the `modification_counter` with the below query:

```
USE StatisticsUpdating;

SELECT s.object_id, sp.modification_counter, s.name,
CONCAT('USE ', DB_NAME(), ';', ' DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id)), ', ', QUOTENAME(s.name), ');') AS ViewHistogram
FROM sys.stats s
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id, s.stats_id) sp
WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('StatMan');
```

I get a `modification_counter` of `60,498`, which is expected.

When I run

```
SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

modification_counter is `0`, as expected.

Now running the same test but switching the COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to either `130`, `140`, or `150`.

When viewing the `modification_counter` with the below query:

```
USE StatisticsUpdating;

SELECT s.object_id, sp.modification_counter, s.name,
CONCAT('USE ', DB_NAME(), ';', ' DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id)), ', ', QUOTENAME(s.name), ');') AS ViewHistogram
FROM sys.stats s
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id, s.stats_id) sp
WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('StatMan');
```

I get a `modification_counter` of `60,498`, which is expected.  Go so far!

When I run

```
SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

It's still at `60,498`!  It didn't do a stat update even though I was expecting it to.

So now I try

```
SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
JOIN StatInformation si ON sm.Id = si.StatManId
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

`modification_counter` is still at `60,498`!  Once again, still didn't update stats.

Than I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM StatMan sm
JOIN StatInformation si ON sm.Id = si.StatManId
WHERE sm.Id = 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

`modification_counter` once again at `60,498`!  Once again, still didn't update stats.

So to get stats to update, I ended up having to run

```
INSERT INTO StatInformation(StatManId, StatLineItem)
SELECT TOP 101 Id, CONCAT('Test Item', CAST(Id AS CHAR(200)))
FROM StatMan
WHERE Id NOT IN
(
    SELECT StatManId
    FROM StatInformation
);
```

Where `SELECT TOP 101` is the magic number for table `StatInformation` to get a stat update.

So I'm not exactly sure why it's behaving differently between `130-150` and `160`.  Especially when all Microsoft documents say compatibility level `130` and above should behave the same.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: Test scenarios 1: "I get a modification_counter of NULL, which is not expected." - for an equality operation against a unique index it doesn't really need to autocreate statistics. It can just assume 1 row

Comment: That makes sense.  The thing is, why does it behave differently on 160?

Comment: No idea why it has suddenly decided that it needs statistics for this in 2022. It doesn't seem to use them as it still uses `CSelCalcUniqueKeyFilter` and it doesn't affect the 1 row estimate whether you search for a value inside or outside the histogram. But anyway I think the vast majority or all of the behaviour you are asking about can be explained as you are expecting `WHERE sm.Id = 200` to cause a stats auto create/update whereas on previous compat levels SQL Server doesn't care about column stats for this query. `StatisticsInfo` in XML execution plan is only present at `160` compat

Comment: (showing no column statistics were loaded at previous compat levels)

Comment: You're correct that my test was very narrow in scope.  For example, if I changed `WHERE Id = 200` to  `WHERE Id BETWEEN 200 AND 201`, it would do a stat update.   Or if I remove the primary key, it wouldn't be able to infer uniqueness so it would do  a stat update.  Overall, the behavior change is not a big deal and may even be a bug?

Comment: May or may not be a bug. Maybe the cardinality estimation has changed in some subtle way where the column stats do make a difference now so it is expected that it should now refer to column stats and create/update them as needed. But the internals of how cardinality estimation are done are not documented and very subject to change when moving between compatibility levels